# Stored procedure, no values returned?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

my first stored procedure is created but calling the procedure in phpmyadmin gives 1 row as result, but in php it is NULL??

```
$res = $mysqli->query("CALL ts_open_uitdagingen");
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
var_dump($res->fetch_assoc());
```

in my page it displays: NULL

in phpMyAdmin the result is one row:
open_uitdagingen
3

what is the missing link in my thoughts?

Comment: `$res->fetch_assoc()` is not idempotent

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't know why, but with print_r I do get the results!

```
print_r($row);
```

Displays: Array ( [open_uitdagingen] => 3 )

So i did get the result, but why var_dump($res->fetch_assoc()); gives an empty result? I still don't know, but i can go on now an that counts:)